# Is there any possibility in PVA to get connection data from MS Teams?

Tags: power-virtual-agents

I'd like to run a bot made with PVA in Microsoft Teams. Is there any possibility to get any information about the connection like IP-Address, Computer-/Device Name or MAC-Address of the computer where MS Teams is running and pass these information to the bot?

Any ideas welcome! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Using Teams as your PVA consumption channel, you will not be able to access to such information, sorry.

You can just get the `UserID` and `UserDisplayName` by using the Authentication mecanism (see [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/power-virtual-agents/advanced-end-user-authentication?WT.mc_id=AI-MVP-5003365#authentication-when-using-only-for-teams-configuration)), but it does not seem to fit your needs.

In fact, even with other channels, you will not get these details. I think the only way with Bot Framework / Power Virtual Agent would be to use the "webchat" channel and to implement the collection and transmission of these details on the client side using the "backchannel" mechanism.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Nicolas! I was afraid of that. I will try to implement the backchannel method.